# Article and Image Side by Side alignment not working properly

Tags: html, css, image

```
<doctype html!>
<html lang="en-US">
<style>
heading{
text-align:center;
color:magenta;
font-family:Ubuntu Condensed;
font-size:45px;
font-style:italic;
display:block;
}
subheading{
text-align:left;
text-decoration:underline;
font-family:Ubuntu;
font-size:18px;
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
} 
article{
font-family:Ubuntu Mono;
font-size:18px;
display:inline-block;
width:800px;
}
div{
margin-left:100px;
margin-right:100px;
border:5px;
border-radius:25px;
box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px #888888;
background-color:#E6BC93;
padding:10px;
}
talas{
font-family:Serif;

footer {
position: absolute;
text-align:center;
bottom:0px;
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
}
img{
position:absolute;
}

</style>
<title> Mridangam </title>
<body>
<div>
<heading>The Mridangam</heading>


<subheading>Mridangam In Hindu Scriptures</subheading>
<article>
In ancient Hindu sculpture, painting, and mythology, the mridangam is often depicted as the instrument of choice for a number of deities including Ganesha (the remover of     obstacles) and Nandi, who is the vehicle and follower of Shiva. Nandi is said to have played the mridangam during Shiva's primordial tandava dance, causing a divine rhythm to resound across the heavens. The mridangam is thus also known as "Deva Vaadyam," or "Divine Instrument".
</article><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/Wiki-    mridangam.jpg/250px-Wiki-mridangam.jpg" />
<hr>
<br/>
<subheading>Basic Lessons:</subheading>
<talas>
<ul>
<a href="adi-tala.html">    <li>Adi Tala</li></a>   <br/>
<a href="rupaka-tala.html"> <li>Rupaka Tala</li></a><br/>
<a href="misra-chapu-tala.html"><li>Misra Chapu</li></a><br/>
<a href="ganda-chapu-tala.html"><li>Ganda Chapu</li></a><br/>
</ul>
</talas>

</div>



<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<footer><center>&copy Copyright of Vishal Subramanyam</footer></center>
</body></html>
```

The problem is that between the subheading 'Mridangam In Hindu Scriptures', there is a big gap. As the user can see, there is some space between the subheading and the article. I want the article text to be to the left of the image of the instrument. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
This is the output I am currently getting. You can clearly see the gap between the sub-heading and the article. Below is a link to my picture as I cannot post a picture because I don't have enough reputation:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8uVrRovWgCOUjNKbWk5SGRGWGs&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Your css is invalid.

```
talas{
    font-family:Serif;
```

Here is a missing bracket. Change it to:

```
talas{
    font-family:Serif;
}
```

Comment: This has got nothing to do with my problem. Even if I correct the CSS the problem is going to persist.

Comment: Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/4a94dvoc/ and point me, what do you mean, GAP? Or show me an image what is the desired output.